# Add item to bst

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I have a custom .bst made with [`makebst`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/). It works well, except I would like to add an extra field for translated works. Ideally I would like something like "translated by [translator]" to appear after the book's title, where [translator] is the translator's name, when appropriate. I have the information stored in my .bib (under translator), but I don't know how to code the .bst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution, based upon [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110075/adding-condition-into-bibtex-bst-file). The `book` function becomes

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.translator output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.sentence
  format.eprint output
  fin.entry
}
```

where I have defined a new function

```
FUNCTION {format.translator}
{ translator "translator" format.names
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
  {
     "translated by " swap$ *
  } if$
}
```